# Firebase Hosting - Store projectId in git version control

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

One can select a project to deploy their app to, using `firebase use PROJECT_ID`.

I've an interesting pattern - I've multiple firebase hosted applications (projects) on the different branches of a git repo, and I often need to switch between them. When I issue `firebase deploy`, often it picks the wrong project and deploy there.

Is there a way to configure the projectId for firebase hosting within my code, so that when changing branches, the right project is automatically selected for deployment?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's not in .firebaserc?  I see a project ID in there in my project.  It should be under projects/default.

Comment: Interesting. I just created a clean repo, and now it's there. Although when I try to change it using 'firebase use XYZ', it doesn't update in .firebaserc. 
The CLI docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli say "When you select a Firebase project during project initialization, the project is automatically assigned the alias of default.", so I guess I'll have to re-initialize it to change the default?